# Swift 4 migration

Tags: swift, xcode, migration

Good morning,

I have Xcode 10.1 and Swift 3.2
I am trying to migrate to Swift 4.0, but unfortunately I have got these errors:

A. Multiple commands produce '/Users..../path/'
1. Target "ApplicationTests"
2. Target "ApplicationUITests"
3. Target "Application"

B. Cycle in dependencies between targets "ApplicationTests" and "Application"; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle path: Application Tests -> Application -> Application Tests
Target build order preserved because "Parallelize Build" is off.

Maybe someone knowns how to fix it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your app really doesn't have that cycle stated, you might want to clean and rebuild your app. Clean by pressing `Cmd + Option + Shift + k` and then rebuild/rerun your application. That usually solves some build problems in Xcode.

**Edit**

Also, you might want to check your Build System to use the new or legacy one. Go to `File -> Project Settings (or Workspace Settings)` and configure it properly. Try using legacy build system; New build system still presents odd behavior sometimes.